# Forcing one more iteration of loop?

Tags: c#

```
int iterationMax = 1;
double actualMax = 0;
int A = 3;

List<double> tmp = new List<double> { 400, 0, -300, 400, 600 ,300, 400, 
                                      1200, 900, 400, 1200, 1500};
List<double> listMax = new List<double>();
for (int i = 0; i < tmp.Count; i++)
{
    if (iterationMax < A) // A == 3
    {
        if (tmp[i] > actualMax)
        {
            actualMax = tmp[i];
        }
        iterationMax++;
    }
    else
    {
        listMax.Add(actualMax);
        actualMax = 0;
        iterationMax = 1;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("\nMaxs: ");
foreach (double max in listMax)
{
    Console.Write(max + ", ");
}
```

List tmp holds = `{ 400,0,-300|400,600,300|400,1200,900|400,1200,1500}`,
Produce `400, 600, 1200, 1200`,
Should be `400, 600, 1200, 1500`. I don't know how to enter else statement to add 1500 to list.

I just want to get max from every 3 elements.

Comment: Isn't there a typo? `listMax.Add(aktualnyMax)` Should be `listMax.Add(actualMax)`

Comment: Yeah i was writing it in different language so i had to change the names of variables

Comment: List<double> tmp = new List<double>() { 400,0,-300,400,600,300,400,1200,900,400,1200,1500};

            List<double> maxes = tmp.Select((x,i) => new { value = x, index = i}).GroupBy(x => (int)(x.index/3)).Select(x => x.Select(y => y.value).Max()).ToList();

Comment: Tip for writing to console. To avoid the trailing comma, you could do Console.Write(string.Join(", ", listMax));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix for your code would be:

```
var A = 3;

int iterationMax = 0;
double actualMax = 0;

List<double> tmp = new List<double> {400,0,-300,400,600,300,400,1200,900,400,1200,1500};
List<double> listMax = new List<double>();
for (int i = 0; i < tmp.Count; i++)
{
    if (iterationMax < A) // A == 3
    {
        if (tmp[i] > actualMax)
        {
            actualMax = tmp[i];
        }
        iterationMax++;
    }

    if (iterationMax == A)
    {
        listMax.Add(actualMax);
        actualMax = 0;
        iterationMax = 0;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("\nMaxs: ");
foreach (double max in listMax)
{
    Console.Write(max + ", ");
}
```

As others have said, start `iterationMax` from `0` and turn that `else` into an `if (iterationMax == A)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot that is what i was looking for.

Comment: The second if is equivalent to an else

Comment: Nope, cause in case with two if statements they are both checked in every iteration. When u use if and else, the else is executed only when the if is false. That is why in the last iteration my else was skipped.

Answer (score 4):

When one needs to perform manipulations on collection it is many times nicer to use Linq.

Use `GroupBy` in the `index/3` and as it is an `int` each 3 following items will have a different `key`. Then for each group select the maximum value:

```
var items = new int[] { 400, 0, -300, 400, 600, 300, 400, 1200, 900 };

var results = items.Select((item, index) => new { item, index })
                   .GroupBy(item => item.index / 3)
                   .Select(group => group.Max(item => item.item));
//400, 600, 1200
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting iterationMax to 0 in initialization and under else should solve your issue.

Currently your if structure will only check the first two out of three elements. Since 1500 is element #3, it will not be checked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, when `iterationMax` reaches 3, you don't do anything with the value in temp, that loop is lost.

```
for (int i = 0; i < tmp.Count; i++)
{
    if (tmp[i] > actualMax)
    {
        actualMax = tmp[i];
    }
    iterationMax++;

    if (iterationMax > A)
    {
        listMax.Add(actualMax);
        actualMax = 0;
        iterationMax = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah i didnt know how to solve this, but stack as always helps. I had brainfreeze